# How to get the exchange rate?

Tags: axapta

I have a query that uses the SalesLine table, I need to get the exchange rate. I see the exchange rate in the CUSTTRANS and CUSTINVOICEJOUR table, but I can't see how to join to those tables.

Can anyone help me with the sql join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange rates can be a bit more complicated than a simple join with things like cross currency triangulation, but the data is contained in `ExchRates` and `Currency` tables in AX 2009.